# WebGL Renders pixelated lines

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

Im trying to render simple shapes ( circles, rectangles and triangles , however, they become very pixelated when WebGL Renders them.

Shader code:

```
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
 // convert the rectangle points from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
 vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

 // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
 vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

 // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
 vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

 gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
```

Here is my code for rendering the circle:

```
var WebGLRenderer = (function () {

  function WebGLRenderer() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    this.gl = this.canvas.getContext('webgl') || this.canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')
    if (!this.gl) {
      throw Error('Your browser does not support WebGL')
      return
    }

    // Programs
    this.rectangleProgram = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(this.gl, ['2d-vertex-shader', '2d-fragment-shader'])

    // Locations
    this.rectanglePoisitionLocation = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'a_position')

    // Uniforms
    this.rectangleResolutionLocation = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'u_resolution')
    this.rectangleColorLocation = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'u_color')

    // this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    this.rectanglePositionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer)

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
  }


  WebGLRenderer.prototype.clearCanvas = function (color) {
    var rgba = color.getColor()
    this.gl.clearColor(...rgba)
    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  }

  WebGLRenderer.prototype.drawCircle = function (x, y, radius, color) {
    // Render circle
    // For now user rectangleProgram
    this.gl.useProgram(this.rectangleProgram)
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.rectanglePoisitionLocation)
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer)
    this.circleBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.rectanglePositionBuffer)
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.circleBuffer)

    // Setup circle
    var circleVertices = [x, y]
    var numFans = 360
    var anglePerFan = (2 * Math.PI) / numFans
    for (var i = 0; i <= numFans; i++) {
      var angle = anglePerFan * (i + 1)
      var angledX = x + Math.cos(angle) * radius
      var angledY = y + Math.sin(angle) * radius
      circleVertices.push(angledX, angledY)
      // circleVertices.push()
    }
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(circleVertices), this.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
    // this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    var size = 2
    var type = this.gl.FLOAT
    var normalize = false
    var stride = 0
    var offset = 0
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.rectanglePoisitionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

    this.gl.uniform2f(this.rectangleResolutionLocation, this.gl.canvas.width, this.gl.canvas.height)

    // Color
    var colorArray = color.getColor()
    this.gl.uniform4fv(this.rectangleColorLocation, colorArray)

    // Draw rectangle
    var primitiveType = this.gl.TRIANGLE_FAN
    // var primitiveType = this.gl.POINTS
    var offset = 0
    var count = circleVertices.length / size
    // var count = positions.length / size
    this.gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count)
  }

  WebGLRenderer.prototype.render = function (time) {
    this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.gl.canvas.width, this.gl.canvas.height)

    var delta = Math.sin(time / 1000) * 10
    this.clearCanvas(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
    var rectangleColor = new Color(0, 65, 255, 255)
    var width = 50
    var height = 50
    var circleColor = new Color(0, 167, 255, 255)
    this.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, circleColor)

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
  }
  return WebGLRenderer
})()


function Color(r, g, b, a) {
  this.r = r
  this.g = g
  this.b = b
  this.a = a
  this.getColor = function () {
    return [r / 255, g / 255, b / 255, a / 255]
  }
}

var renderer = new WebGLRenderer()
```

Results: blurry circle (everything I render with WebGL is blurry)

See fiddle for results: https://jsfiddle.net/xLwmngav/1/

Expected results: a smooth round circle

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably want to read [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed out in [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html) canvases have 2 sizes, their resolution (how many pixels are in them) and the size they are displayed.

Generally you want the resolution to match or exceed the size the canvas is displayed. The best way to do that is to to check, just before rendering, if the canvas's resolution matches the size it's displayed and if it's not to resize it with a function like this

```
  function resize(canvas) {
    // Lookup the size the browser is displaying the canvas.
    const desiredWidth  = canvas.clientWidth;
    const desiredHeight = canvas.clientHeight;

    // Check if the canvas is not the same size.
    if (canvas.width  !== desiredWidth ||
        canvas.height !== desiredHeight) {

      // Make the canvas the same size
      canvas.width  = desiredWidth;
      canvas.height = desiredHeight;
    }
  }
```

And use it like this

```
function render() {
  resize(canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  ... draw here ...

  ...
```

example:

```js
function resize(canvas) {
  // Lookup the size the browser is displaying the canvas.
  const desiredWidth  = canvas.clientWidth;
  const desiredHeight = canvas.clientHeight;

  // Check if the canvas is not the same size.
  if (canvas.width  !== desiredWidth ||
      canvas.height !== desiredHeight) {

    // Make the canvas the same size
    canvas.width  = desiredWidth;
    canvas.height = desiredHeight;
  }
}

var WebGLRenderer = (function () {

  function WebGLRenderer() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    this.gl = this.canvas.getContext('webgl') || this.canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')
    if (!this.gl) {
      throw Error('Your browser does not support WebGL')
      return
    }

    // Programs
    this.rectangleProgram = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(this.gl, ['2d-vertex-shader', '2d-fragment-shader'])

    // Locations
    this.rectanglePoisitionLocation = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'a_position')

    // Uniforms
    this.rectangleResolutionLocation = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'u_resolution')
    this.rectangleColorLocation = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.rectangleProgram, 'u_color')

    // this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    this.rectanglePositionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer)

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
  }


  WebGLRenderer.prototype.clearCanvas = function (color) {
    var rgba = color.getColor()
    this.gl.clearColor(...rgba)
    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  }

  WebGLRenderer.prototype.drawCircle = function (x, y, radius, color) {
    // Render circle
    // For now user rectangleProgram
    this.gl.useProgram(this.rectangleProgram)
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.rectanglePoisitionLocation)
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer)
    this.circleBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer()
    // this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.rectanglePositionBuffer)
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.circleBuffer)

    // Setup circle
    var circleVertices = [x, y]
    var numFans = 360
    var anglePerFan = (2 * Math.PI) / numFans
    for (var i = 0; i <= numFans; i++) {
      var angle = anglePerFan * (i + 1)
      var angledX = x + Math.cos(angle) * radius
      var angledY = y + Math.sin(angle) * radius
      circleVertices.push(angledX, angledY)
      // circleVertices.push()
    }
    /*var circleVertices = [
      x, y,
      15, 18,
      5, 18,
      0, 10,
      4, 1,
      14, 1,
      20, 9,
      15, 18
    ]*/
    // three 2d points
    // TODO: Research static draw
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(circleVertices), this.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
    // this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    var size = 2
    var type = this.gl.FLOAT
    var normalize = false
    var stride = 0
    var offset = 0
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.rectanglePoisitionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

    this.gl.uniform2f(this.rectangleResolutionLocation, this.gl.canvas.width, this.gl.canvas.height)

    // Color
    var colorArray = color.getColor()
    this.gl.uniform4fv(this.rectangleColorLocation, colorArray)

    // Draw rectangle
    var primitiveType = this.gl.TRIANGLE_FAN
    // var primitiveType = this.gl.POINTS
    var offset = 0
    var count = circleVertices.length / size
    // var count = positions.length / size
    this.gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count)
  }

  WebGLRenderer.prototype.render = function (time) {
    resize(this.gl.canvas);
    this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.gl.canvas.width, this.gl.canvas.height)

    var delta = Math.sin(time / 1000) * 10
    this.clearCanvas(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
    var rectangleColor = new Color(0, 65, 255, 255)
    var width = 50
    var height = 50
    var circleColor = new Color(0, 167, 255, 255)
    this.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, circleColor)

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
  }
  return WebGLRenderer
})()


function Color(r, g, b, a) {
  this.r = r
  this.g = g
  this.b = b
  this.a = a
  this.getColor = function () {
    return [r / 255, g / 255, b / 255, a / 255]
  }
}

var renderer = new WebGLRenderer()

window.WebGLRenderer = WebGLRenderer
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;  /* prevents scrollbar */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <!-- vertex shader -->
  <script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec2 a_position;
  
  uniform vec2 u_resolution;
  
  void main() {
     // convert the rectangle points from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
     vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
  
     // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
     vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
  
     // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
     vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
  
     gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
  }
  </script>
  <!-- fragment shader -->
  <script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  
  uniform vec4 u_color;
  
  void main() {
     gl_FragColor = u_color;
  }
  </script>
  <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Follow up question; the cirlce is still a little blurry when zoomed in, so does it have to be anti aliased in the shader? And can you do it some other way than using anti-aliasing in the shader? And any direction for implementing anti-aliasing in a shader would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: double the resolution of the canvas in `resize`. Example:  `const desiredWidth  = canvas.clientWidth * 2;
    const desiredHeight = canvas.clientHeight * 2;` would be one way

Answer (score 0):

The canvas defaults to a width and height of 300x150 pixels. These are attributes of the `<canvas>` element, not CSS properties. By scaling to `100vw` by `100vh`, you're just stretching those 300x150 pixels out to fill the screen.

To actually get a 1:1 mapping from canvas pixels to screen pixels, you need to set the width and height of the canvas to the size of the window:

```
this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth
this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

You may also want to listen for the `resize` event on `window` and update the canvas size accordingly.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kL1a2zpr/